# DB error on tag page after installation

Tags: error, database, tags

I'm new to CiviCRM and just installed it (v. 4.7.17) on Wordpress 4.7.3

When I access the tag management page (wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Ftag&reset=1), I get a DB Error + a display bug.

Error is

```
Expression #12 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'civicrm.child.id' which is not functionnally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause ; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by, 1055
```

And debug info is in the image attached.

[image]
Does anybody know how to sort this out?

thanks

Thomas

Comment: What database software & version are you using?

Comment: i am with MySQL 5.7.17

Answer (score 1):

ok, finally got it working by adding the following lines to the config file located at
*/etc/mysql/my.cnf*

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

But looks like a bug anyway..?!